# XRAY database sync seemingly stuck

Tags: jfrog-xray

When navigating to XRAY -> Settings -> database sync I see the below where the progress gets

[image: Seemingly stuck]

5 minutes will pass and it does not go up or get any closer to completion. This is the first time that this has happened to us and am wondering what could cause this.

Some last lines of logs from the various containers
xray-persist

```
Start Deleting files with message Id fe181e2d-f571-4 
2023-01-17 [jfxps] [INFO ] [f8] [persist_worker:88] [main] Persist worker id 6 is processing message from persist --> ba/typed_ast-1.5.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl 

2023-01-17 [jfxps] [INFO ] [f8] [storage_service:233] [main] Persisting component graph pypi://typed-ast:1.5.4 to graph db

2023-01-17 [jfxps] [INFO ] [f8] [persist_worker:162] [main] Sending index complete notification to binary manager: default componentId pypi://typed-ast:1.5.4 

2023-01-17 [jfxps] [INFO ] [f8] [persist_worker:120] [main] Persist worker id 6 has completed to process message ba/typed_ast-1.5.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

xray-analysis is similar having `Analysis Worker id X processing` and then `Analysis Worked id X has completed`
xray-indexer is similar again, but does have a `Start deleting files with message Id`

#### A couple of things I have tried

I have paused / aborted the sync but upon trying to sync again it gets stuck.

I have tried restarting the xray and artifactory statefulsets to no avail.

#### Other details

Artifactory: 7.19.13

Xray: 3.26.1

Using a postgresql database

We have had to restart the database once before but this problem was still present before we restarted it.

Comment: Is this getting stuck exactly at 95%? Can you check xray-server-service.log file for any errors?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif Thanks for your reply! It's actually now at 88% as it's now 420/476. The xray-server pod recently doesn't have any ERRORs in it but did near the beginning. Here's a pastebin containing the first logs and the most recent ones https://pastebin.com/ksAXXgRr

Comment: As no errors are seen, check for slow-running queries in the DB and if 3000 IOPS are opened as mentioned in the system requirements https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements.